# Solution of an equation with $3$ variables

Tags: linear-algebra

I've been thinking about a solution for the following equation for integers $x, y, z$:
$$6 = (x-y)^2 + (y-z)^2 + (x-z)^2$$
A possible approach would probably be to set $(x-y)^2 = a$, $(y-z)^2 = b$ and $(x-z)^2 = c$.
Now, the euqation woud look like this:
$$6 = a + b + c$$
Hence, the only possible solutions would be $$(a, b, c) = (4, 1, 1)$$ $$(a, b, c) = (1, 4, 1)$$ $$(a, b, c) = (1, 1, 4)$$
Now one could formulate equation for $x, y$ and $z$. However, this approach would be very time consuming. Is there a simpler solution to the problem?

Comment: $$\{\{x\to -6,y\to -7,z\to -5\},\{x\to 58,y\to 59,z\to 60\},\{x\to 190,y\to 191,z\to
   189\},\{x\to 74,y\to 72,z\to 73\}\}$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. How did you figure that out?

Comment: *Mathematica*..

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  This question is not [tag:linear-algebra]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Let $x-y=a$ etc.

$\implies a+b+c=0\iff c=-?$

$$6=a^2+b^2+c^2=2a^2+2ab+2b^2\iff2a^2+a(2b)+2b^2-6=0$$

$$a=\dfrac{-2b\pm\sqrt{12(4-b^2)}}4=\dfrac{-b\pm\sqrt{3(4-b^2)}}2$$

For integer $a,$ $$b^2=4,1\implies b=\pm2,\pm1$$

We shall get the same set of values for $c,$ if we start with $b=-(c+a)$

So, $(a,b,c)\in(1,1,-2)$ or $\in(-1,-1,2)$ as $a+b+c=0$

Comment: I really apperciate your help :)  But why must $a + b + c$ be equal to $0$?

Comment: @MichaelSchreiber,  $$y-z=b, z-x=c$$ right?

Comment: Now I get it, thank you very much for your help :)